# Mamzeirim and Slaves

Tags: halacha, mishna, mamzer, slave-serve-eved-avadim

**If Reuben's sister, Hanna, is a slave and she and Reuben have sexual intercourse, are their children slaves or mamzeirim?**

> Acc. to the Mishna in Yevamot 4:12-13, the offspring of a forbidden
>   union, the penalty for which is *karet*, is a mamzer. That is the
>   opinion of Rabbi Shimon haTeimani in mishna 13 - contra the opinions
>   of Rabbi Akiva and Rabbi Yehoshua - and is understood to be the
>   opinion of the sages (contra Akiva) in mishna 12.
>
> Acc. to the Mishna in Ketubot 3:12, the offspring of such a forbidden
>   union - one in which the woman would have been permitted to another -
>   is a mamzer. The offspring, however, of another forbidden union - one
>   in which the woman could *not* have been permitted to another -
>   follows the woman in status. The practical upshot of this mishna is
>   that the child of a gentile woman or a slave girl (neither of whom can
>   contract kiddushin with anybody) is either a gentile or a slave.
>
> If there is a brother and a sister (Reuben and Hanna in my example)
>   and she is a slave, they now belong to two of the different types of
>   relationships delineated from one another in Ketubot. They are
>   siblings, and the penalty for sexual intercourse is *karet*
>   (Mishna, Keritot 1:1; cf: Leviticus 18:9, 29). That means, based on
>   both Ketubot and Yevamot, their offspring are mamzeirim. And yet,
>   being a slave, she cannot contract kiddushin with *any* man, which means
>   that their offspring (based on Ketubot) are slaves.

Comment: Just to clarify: by "slave" you mean _ama ivriya_?

Comment: I'm referring to a Hebrew slave, yes. That's the category being referred to in Ketubot, the non-Jewish slave simply being not Jewish. (I don't know whether or not the correct term is אמה, so I can't respond to that part of your question - is an אמה bound by the same regulations as other עבדים? I don't know.)

Comment: Er... see the answer.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but can you provide attribution for the quote you've placed in blockquotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must mean a non-Jewish (actually, quasi-Jewish) slave, a "shifcha." (I.e. she was born non-Jewish, then underwent a part-conversion when she became a slave.) A born-Jewish, "ama ivriyah" goes free automatically upon reaching puberty, so that case is moot.

I don't know whether the partial conversion given to a *shifcha* already wipes out all existing relationships (as it does with full-blown conversion), but the point is moot. [As the last Mishnah in Kiddushin Chapter 3 observes](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Mishnah/Seder_Nashim/Tractate_Kiddushin/Chapter_3/14) (and the Halacha follows Rabbi Tarfon's opinion):

> רבי טרפון אומר:‏
>   יכולין הם ממזרים ליטהר.‏
>   כיצד?‏
>   ממזר שנשא שפחה, הוולד עבד;‏
>   שחררו, נמצא הבן בן חורין.‏

The offspring of a male mamzer and female *shifcha* is just plain *eved* (*eved kna'ani*, to be specific), not *eved mamzer*. There is no room in the category for any flavor of *eved*, just plain *eved*. Thus to the best of my knowledge the same would apply here, the offspring of a *shifcha* is just plain *eved*; whether the father was a normal Jew, a non-Jew, a *mamzer* Jew, or a forbidden-relation Jew.

Comment: Thank you, Shalom. Do you have sources for any of that? I wouldn't mind seeing it inside, if you don't mind. Especially because it appears to provide a means of ridding somebody of mamzer status: by reproducing with a shifcha, he creates an eved, not a mamzer (!?).

Comment: @ShimonbM, that's exactly right. See the Mishnah. This possibility of a solution has been raised in contemporary cases of *mamzers*, but the problem (practically, halachicly, secular-legally, *and* ethically) is where exactly do you get a *shifcha* today (I was going to say "you can't order them online", but sadly that may not be so true).

Comment: @ShimonbM משנה קידושין ג:יג 

רבי טרפון אומר יכולין ממזרים ליטהר כיצד ממזר שנשא שפחה הולד עבד שחררו נמצא הבן בן חורין but if I understand correctly, Rabbi Mordochai Willig rules this can't be done nowadays (at least in normal countries) because of Dina Demalchuta Dina and the slave wouldn't be a slave.

Comment: What's a part-conversion?

Comment: @KinnardHockenhull a non-Jewish slave in the Talmud was given an immersion in the mikvah and obligated in all "don't-do" commandments. Hence, "part-conversion"