# Giyores marrying a cohen and their offspring

Tags: halacha, marriage, conversion-to-judaism, kohen-priest

If a Cohen married a giyores (convert), they had children born after the conversion of their mother, and the children had to do a geirus lechumra because the mothers' conversion was not done by reliable rabbanim, can the daughter marry a cohen?

Comment: Racheli, it sounds from your questions like you are thinking about a specific case of someone you know. You really need to speak to a rabbi who knows you with the details to get a final ruling. This site isn't a rabbi and it isn't cut out for handling complex real life rulings like yours.

Answer (score 5):

At first glance the daughter is either herself a convert, or the product of a kohen's prohibited marriage to a convert, i.e. a *chalala.* Either way she'd be prohibited from marrying a Kohen.

Comment: but ths son is in a greater problem.

Comment: What's the problem with the son?

Comment: @kouty, how so? If he's not halachically Jewish, he's fine. If he is, then he's a challal, which sucks for his kids.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt precisely! It is a big kula to say that he is not halachically jew

Comment: @kouty, so a son of a Kohen and a giyores of questionable status is a challal rather than being of questionable status due to his mother?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38396/discussion-between-noach-mi-frankfurt-and-kouty).

Comment: What's a shifcha and do the still exist?

Comment: @racheliappelbaum please see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28114/can-the-descendants-of-a-mamzer-ever-become-full-jews . Any process by which a *mamzer* man could father a non-*mamzer* child would also apply to a *chalal* fathering a non-*chalal* child.